# Google Glass: Can Android and Google Glass application communicates with each other?

Tags: android, google-glass

The idea is to create an android app which will directly talk to a google glass application to trigger few commands like take picture, record video, video call etc. The data collected by google glass application should again need to send back to specific Android app.

Thanks!!

Comment: What is your question? If it's possible? Everything is possible. You have the internet.

Comment: If it's possible, could you please share any url where it has been explained? I tried to google it for sometime but without much success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. I can think of two options:

1. Use Bluetooth
2. Use a server - send the command id to the server from the phone and then read the command id from the Glass